# Lock screen unactive for 8 seconds - Exchange security setup on Android 4.1.2

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, lock-screens

Can someone reproduce this issue.

I have setup exchange account on my SGS2 with Android 4.1.2. When you setup exchange on android it is required by security policy of exchange server to have screen lock on - in my case it is secured with PIN.

When i try to unlock the phone, my screen is not active, i can just wait and after about 8 second it responsive again and i can unlock it. This doesn't have every time. Let's say 5 times/day .. probably some issue with light sensor.

Please don't post solutions like "You can install 3rd party program ... ", i want to have this security enabled.

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you suspect the light sensor?